# Eclipse me .res file extension

Tags: eclipse, java-me, resources, multiple-languages

I have application to rebuild in Eclipse which has an option to choose a language. It has a res folder with few .res files(one file for each language, like so English.res, Spanish.res) that are used by the app. When opened in Notepad I can read almost all of it (it contains strings that are fetched by the app during run process based on the app's active language) but as soon as I try to edit the string and run the app, it throws NullPointerException... Does anyone know or faced this type of files or maybe knows how to open them for editing, what program to use? When I google it it says the best option is to use Visual Studio but the file cannot be recognized by VS...
Everything in that file is written in one line with funny combination of signs for "new line" like: square or two squares + "Z".

Please any help or advice?
Thanks

Comment: How were these files created?

Comment: To be honest I've no idea.. They were just there when app was created. Maybe they were added , maybe generated by eclipse I can't say... I've tried to use Resource editor plugin for eclipse but I'm getting result similar to what i'v described earlier...